# ROSTutorialsWritingPublisherSubscriber(c++) CMakeLists.txt include_directories

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have done the tutorial successfully, catkin_make and execution work.

The tutorial says:

```
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

But I did, and it still works:

```
include_directories( ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

So , the word **include** is optional? why?
Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205548/rostutorialswritingpublishersubscriber(c++)-cmakelists.txt-include_directories/) by [marilia15](https://answers.ros.org/users/5506/marilia15/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2015-03-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Adding **include** is only necessary if your package contains an `include/` subdirectory with headers needed for compiling some of your C++ programs.

If there are no such references, the **include** is unnecessary, but harmless.

For more details, see: http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/building_executables.html

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2015-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1